# pass json from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Im trying to pass a list of json from my controller to my view but i am missing a big piece of the puzzle. This is the controller method:

```
 public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            var model = new ViewModel();
            model.Places = new List<Place>
            {

                new Place() {Id = 1, Catch = "Gädda", PlaceName = "Arboga", GeoLat = 59.394861, GeoLong = 15.854361},
                new Place() {Id = 2, Catch = "Aborre", PlaceName = "Fis", GeoLat = 59.394861, GeoLong = 15.845361}

            };

            return Json(model.Places, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is the var in the view to which i am trying to send the list of json:

```
var data = [];
```

Any tips on how to go about this? I really have no idea where to start. Thanks!
For simplicitys sake, lets say I have a button in the view that calls `GetList()`

EDIT:
The code that querys the API:

```
// Using the JQuery "each" selector to iterate through the JSON list and drop marker pins
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
                        'map': map,
                        'title': item.PlaceName
                    });
```

(At this point I should add that this code comes from a tutorial:)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/629913/Google-Maps-in-MVC-with-Custom-InfoWindow

Comment: First, make sure your id's are unique. They both say 1 now.

Comment: Sorry, I did a sloppy copy/paste =)

Comment: Where's the code you use to query the `GetList` API?

Comment: Check edit please, I updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming jquery and ajax, then the following would work for you:

```
$(function(){
    $('#yourbuttonid').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            // in a real scenario, use data-attrs on the html
            // rather than linking directly to the url
            url: '@Url.Action("GetList", "yourcontroller")',
            context: document.body
        }).done(function(serverdata) {
            data = serverdata;
            // as per your edit -now loop round the data var
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {...});
        });
    });
});
```

you'll have to tweak to suit, but basically, you're sending an ajax request to your controller and then passing the returned data into your data[] var.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im sure I can get it to work with this info. I´ll be back to accept! Thanks again!

Comment: pleasure - no problem!